# show pixel value of .TIF image on the basis of X Y coordinates in c#

Tags: c#

i am in trouble. how to read 1MB .tif file with bitmap class in c# and have to show pixel value of this .tif image on the basis of X Y coordinates. I searched google lot but not find any answer yet.

```
string imgPath;
            imgPath = @"C:\Documents and Settings\shree\Desktop\2012.06.09.15.35.42.2320.tif";


            Bitmap img;
            img = new Bitmap(imgPath, true);

            MessageBox.Show(Here i have to show pixel value of this .tif image on the basis of X Y coordinates.);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
string imgPath;
imgPath = @"C:\Documents and Settings\shree\Desktop\2012.06.09.15.35.42.2320.tif";

Bitmap img;
img = new Bitmap(imgPath, true);

Color pixelColor = img.GetPixel(50, 50); // 50, 50 or any "VALID" pixel in your bitmap
```

For more info go [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.getpixel)